# How can I access the TestAdapter within my TestMethod

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I want to access the ExpectedResult from my TestMethod

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCase("Pass", ExpectedResult = 1)]
[TestCase("Fail", ExpectedResult = 0)]
[TestCase("PassDueToExpectError", ExpectedResult = -1)]
public int Test(string msg)
{
    int ret = 0;

    switch (msg)
    {
        case "Pass":
            return 1;
        default:
            ret = 0;
            break;
    }
    if (/* ExpectedResult < 0 */) //<- How to test ExpectedResult?
    {
        return -1;
    }

    ret.Should().BeGreaterThan(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Any idea how I can access the ExpedtedResult?

Comment: your test is pretty pointless, it just doesn't test anything. It just converts your `msg`-string into an output-number. There's no system under test (SuT) here. Usually you don't need to access this test-context-information, but instead make your test return ehat your SuT returned. Something like `return mySuT.TheFunctionIWantToTest(myArgs)`.

Comment: Correct, the code snippet should give an insight how I want to check the ExpectedResult. Now I've found an apropriate solution, as you can see on my post below.

Comment: Well, the point is: **why** do you want that? As mentioned you usually just return what your SuT does directly. There's no need to check yourself if that value is equal to the `ExpectedResult` yourself. Of course the proposed solution works, but chances are you're overcomplicating things for nothing.

Comment: Look at TestCase #3. I am expecting an error for this case at a cerain line in my test logics. So therefore a check for `greaterTahan(0)` would make absolutelty no sense.
By setting the ExpectedResult to a certain value I want to let the testMethod know, that it is OK to leave the TestMethod. The TestCase goes to "passed" because the ExpectedResult is met.....some kind of controlled mess :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found following solution, by using:

```
NUnit.Framework.TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.ExpectedResult
```